Why is ModemManager running on my cloud instance, and can I remove it and its dependencies?
I run an Ubuntu server (20.04) on AWS, and for some reason it's running ModemManager. If I say to remove it, it complains about libmm, its support library. I say to remove that, and it complains about fwupd. I have no idea whether this is at all needed for AWS.
I'm trying to pare things down so I can upgrade.
